# Update ZOOM at xubuntu 20.04 focal fossa

Tags: updates, xubuntu, zoom-meeting

I have been using Xubuntu 20.04 focal fossa for a while and now I am trying to update to the latest Zoom version for Ubuntu. When I click in my Zoom account "update to the latest version" it is unsuccessfully downloaded.

Do I have to uninstall and install again the whole package or is there a chance I can do the update from my terminal?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to uninstall it. You can run the following sequence of commands in the terminal:

```
wget -nv -O "$(xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD)"/zoom_amd64.deb 'https://us02web.zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb'
sudo dpkg --skip-same-version -i "$(xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD)"/zoom_amd64.deb
rm -f "$(xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD)"/zoom_amd64.deb
```

Description:

- The first command download the .deb file in your Download folder.
- The second one install it if the new version is different than the current one.
- The last command remove the downloaded deb file.

If you want to speed up or periodically check the presence of updates, you can open your `~/.bashrc` file (for example, using `gedit ~/.bashrc` command) and then add the following lines:

```
# zoom update
if [ -n "$(command -v zoom)" ]; then
  zoom-update() {
    echo "Checking new version availability..."
    wget -nv -O "$(xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD)"/zoom_amd64.deb 'https://us02web.zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb' &> /dev/null
    sudo dpkg --skip-same-version -i "$(xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD)"/zoom_amd64.deb
    rm -f "$(xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD)"/zoom_amd64.deb
  }
fi
```

In this way, you have created a function called `zoom-update` that performs all the tasks. From this moment, you can simply run the command `zoom-update` from the terminal.

To make the function work, close and repen the terminal, or run the command `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I suggest that you don't put it in your .bashrc, as it will download the latest .deb package every time you open a new terminal. For myself, I have dropped your series of commands into a script, zoom-update, and added it to my crontab ($ crontab -e), so that it runs nightly.

Comment: The download command is inside a function, so the it is performed only when the function is called. There isn't any chance to start the download every time you open the terminal :-)

Comment: My mistake, I evidently hadn't read it closely enough